# SwiftUI: How to push to new view from Menu Buttons

Tags: swiftui

I would like to push to a new view from a menu button but my implementation doesn't seem to work. I have searched SO and most solutions use the `NavigationLink`, but doesn't seem to work in a Menu button.

Code:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
    Menu {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: ReadMoreView(),
            label: {
                Label("Read more", systemImage: "ellipses")
            })
    }
    label: {
        Text("Next")
    }
}
```

Other attempts:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
    Menu {
        Button(action: {
           NavigationLink(destination: ReadMoreView())
        }) {
            Label("Read more", systemImage: "ellipses")
        }
    }
    label: {
        Text("Next")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read about programatic navigation in SwiftUI?